# Joomla module and Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, joomla, joomla2.5

I have a module with three drop-downs, in one class, depending on each other. I have the first drop-down that loads the data from MySQL.
I would like that the second one loads the data depending on the first selected value. Currently I have this code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function curPageURL() {
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    return pathname;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#art1').change(function(){
       var $height = $('#art2') ;
       $height.find('option:not([value=default])').remove();
       $.getJSON(curPageURL(), {height:$(this).val()}, function(heights){
          $.each(heights, function(index, height){
              $height.append('<option value="'+height[0]+'">'+height[1]+'</option>');
          });
       });
    });
});
</script>
```

This goes in the `default.php` and if height is set it executes and MySQL statement from another class which works fine and then encodes it to `json`. But firebug is giving me this error

> ERROR: JSON.parse: unexpected character

and as I'm looking in the data it is returning a whole html code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by connecting my module with the component following this tutorial
http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2424982